# Accessing a Class Member from a First-Class Function

Tags: oop, scala, scala-2.8, first-class-functions

I have a case class which takes a list of functions:

```
case class A(q:Double, r:Double, s:Double, l:List[(Double)=>Double])
```

I have over 20 functions defined.  Some of these functions have their own parameters, and some of them also use the `q`, `r`, and `s` values from the case class.  Two examples are:

```
def f1(w:Double) = (d:Double) => math.sin(d) * w
def f2(w:Double, q:Double) = (d:Double) => d * q * w
```

The problem is that I then need to reference `q`, `r`, and `s` twice when instantiating the case class:

```
A(0.5, 1.0, 2.0, List(f1(3.0), f2(4.0, 0.5))) //0.5 is referenced twice
```

I would like to be able to instantiate the class like this:

```
A(0.5, 1.0, 2.0, List(f1(3.0), f2(4.0))) //f2 already knows about q!
```

What is the best technique to accomplish this?  Can I define my functions in a trait that the case class extends?

EDIT: The real world application has 7 members, not 3.  Only a small number of the functions need access to the members.  Most of the functions don't care about them.

Comment: You should be aware that your f1 and f2 methods are generating new `Function1[Double, Double]` instances on each invocation. Given the fact that the function literals do have free variables (`w` and `q`), I guess it's really what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the obvious val declaration:

```
val a = 0.5
A(a, 1.0, 2.0, List(f1(3.0), f2(4.0, a)))
```

Otherwise, `f2` needs a reference to A's `this`, which it will have if it's a member of class A or that particular instance of A. Part of the problem is that the functions are fully baked before the instance of A is instantiated. So you have to define `f2`, as opposed to simply instantiate it, in the context of A.

Finally, you could make the functions partial functions. The first group of params will be as they are, but a second group will be added that is of type A.

Comment: Which of these solutions would you be inclined to use?  Is my idea of using a trait ill-conceived?

Comment: I guess defining the functions inside the class makes sense, since its unlikely they would be very useful elsewhere?

Comment: The trait idea is simply an extension of this idea. Depending on how much reuse you need, probably the best idea. If no reuse, just put 'em in A.

Comment: @sblundy: Can you please take a look at my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238290/assigning-anchor-tags-to-call-javascript-function-dynamically), Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If `q` in `f2` **is always** referring to the `q` in you `case class`, then one quick hack :

```
trait TraitA {                                                                                       
  def q:Double                                                                                       
  def r:Double                                                                                       
  def s:Double                                                                                       

  def f1(w:Double) = (d:Double) => math.sin(d) * w                                                   
  def f2(w:Double) = (d:Double) => d * q * w                                                         
}                                                                                                    

case class A(q:Double, r:Double, s:Double, l:List[(Double)=>Double]=Nil) extends TraitA              

val a=new A(0.5, 1.0, 2.0){override val l= List(f1(3.0), f2(4.0))}
```

Comment: Yes q in f2 always refers to q in the case class. This is exactly what I was considering doing, but not sure its a "best practice"?

Answer (score 1):

One simple idea would be to change the function to take a list of functions that take 3 doubles (q, r, and s) and return a function from double to double. That way those functions that need any of the values can use them, and others just ignore them all.

Comment: Interesting idea.  I am worried this will clutter the function definitions.  My example only has 3 members, but my real world application actually has 7.  Also, only a few of the functions need access to the members.  The majority don't care about them.  I will add these details to the original question.